# undefinded value javascript laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I need when open modal to pass week id and insert data into db with ajax in js
the db columns are :
user_id 
week_id
book_name
author
pages
category
this is php code and there is no data in database

```
 @foreach($weeks as $week)
        @if(Auth::user() == $week->user)
            <table class="table table-bordered tar" id="week">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"> <h4>{{ $week->name }}</h4></i></span>
                <thead>

        <tr>

            <th style="background-color: #f0f0f0; color: #5d6d7e; text-align: center">الخيارات</th>
            <th style="background-color: #3cb774; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center">الإنجاز</th>
            <th style="background-color: #e85657; color: #FFFFFF ; text-align: center">عدد الصفحات</th>
            <th style="background-color: #ff6a06; color: #FFFFFF ; text-align: center">المجال</th>
            <th style="background-color: #2c81ba; color: #FFFFFF ; text-align: center">المؤلف</th>
            <th style="background-color: #0f7864; color: #FFFFFF ; text-align: center">اسم الكتاب</th>
            <th style="background-color: #5d6d7e; color: #FFFFFF ; text-align: center">اليوم</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
                 <tbody class="tbody1">



                    <tr data-pageid="" name="" class="tr1">
                      <td>
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      </td>
                       <td></td>
                       <td></td>
                       <td></td>
                       <td></td>
                       <td></td>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <button type="submit" data-weekid="{{ $week->id }}" id="addbook" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block update_user_button">إضافة كتاب</button>

                     </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

and this js code and no thing in db

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urlSave = '{{ route('add.book') }}';
var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
var weekId = 0;

$(function () {
    $('#error').hide();
    $('.update_user_button').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        var weekId =  $(this).attr('data-weekid');
        var days = $('input[name="day"]').val();
        var book = $('input[name="book"]').val();
        var author = $('input[name="author"]').val();
        var page = $('input[name="page"]').val();
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('_token',token);
        data.append('week_id',weekId);
        data.append('book_name',book);
        data.append('author',author);
        data.append('page',page);

        $('#edit-modal').modal();


        $('#modal-save').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('add.book') }}',
                data: data,
                success:function (data) {
                    $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
                    alert('done');
                },
                error:function (data) {
                    $('#error').show();
                    $('#error').html('');
                    var error = data.responseJSON;
                    //$.each(error,function (k,v) {
                      //  $('#error').append(v + '<br />');

                   // })
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })




        });
    });


});
```

Comment: What is undefined?  I mean i see that the '.update_user_button' does not have a `data-weekid` on it, so that would be undefined for your click handler.  That attribute is on your table, not on the button.

Comment: chang this `m = event.target.dataset['weekid'];` to _something like_ this `m = $(this).attr('data-weekid');`

Comment: m = event.target.dataset['weekid'];
    alert(m);

Comment: Have you defined the token variable ? `_token: token`